# how to get rgb values in percentage in photoshop

Tags: colors, photoshop

how to get RGB values in percentage in photoshop.
and is cmyk percentage values are similar to RGB?

Comment: To gain reputation, and make others to answer your question, accepts the good answers of your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RGB and CMYK are different color modes.

RGB colors are screen colors. It is expressed in absolute values, usually in integer values from 0 to 255, representing the brightness on the screen. The exact range of values depends on the color depth of the image. The higher the value, the more light of that color is added, so the highest color is white.

CMYK colors are printing colors. They are used to represent the amount of ink used for a pixel. This is no absolute value, because it is merely a ratio between the color components. The higher the value, the darker it gets. 100% of each is (near) black, although real black is usually constructed by using 100% of K (key) and about 30% of each of the other components.

Comment: still i want to know if we can get rgb values in percentage....with the help of PHOTOSHOP

Answer (score 0):

integer values from 0 to 255 are for 8 bit color, in the day of 16 or 32 bit color it would make sense to be able to view rgb as percentage values.

this is being added to Adobe lightroom currently does percentaes unless you're in the develop module, in soft proof mode